# Can not upload image with FormData

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, redux-toolkit, form-data

I trying to upload image by post request using FormData but not working.
[Here is the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odjTR.png)

This is my code in Profile.jsx, bacsically is a function that choose image from directory and after that will send file to updateCurrentUserAvatar and post file when click button Submit

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getCurrentUserAvatar, setImage, updateCurrentUserAvatar } from '~/features/superAdminSlice';
import Spinner from '~/layouts/components/Spinner';

const SuperAdminAccountProfile = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const userAvatar = useSelector((state) => state.superadmin.avatar);
    const [imageProfile, setImageProfile] = useState(userAvatar);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getCurrentUserAvatar());
        setImageProfile(userAvatar);
        setLoading(false);
    }, [dispatch, userAvatar]);

    const handleButtonClick = () => {
        const input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'file';
        input.accept = 'image/*';
        input.style.opacity = 0;
        input.style.height = 0;
        input.onchange = (event) => {
            const file = event.target.files[0];
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = () => {
                setImageProfile(reader.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            setImage(file);
        };
        document.body.appendChild(input);
        input.click();
        document.body.removeChild(input);
    };

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (imageProfile) {
            dispatch(updateCurrentUserAvatar(imageProfile));
        }
    };
    return (
        <div style={{ position: 'relative', width: '200px', height: '200px' }}>
            {loading ? (
                <Spinner />
            ) : (
                <>
                    <img src={imageProfile} alt="" style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} />
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        style={{
                            position: 'absolute',
                            top: '50%',
                            left: '50%',
                            transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
                            visibility: 'visible',
                        }}
                        onClick={handleButtonClick}
                    >
                        Change Image
                    </button>
                </>
            )}
            <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                Submit            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SuperAdminAccountProfile;
```

Here is my Slice.js with updateCurrentUserAvatar.

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from '~/api/axios';
import { getAdmins, register, updateStatus } from '~/services/superAdminService';

const initialState = {
    data: [],
    admins: [],
    isLocked: false,
    currentPage: 1,
    pageSize: 5,
    search: '',
    adminId: '',
    count: '',
    avatar: null,
};

export const getAdminData = createAsyncThunk('superadmin/adminList', async ({ currentPage, pageSize, search }) => {
    try {
        const response = await getAdmins(currentPage, pageSize, search);
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

export const updateAdminStatus = createAsyncThunk('superadmin/updateData', async (adminId) => {
    try {
        const response = await updateStatus(adminId);
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

export const createAdmin = createAsyncThunk('superadmin/createAdmin', async (payload) => {
    try {
        const response = await register({
            email: payload.email,
            fullname: payload.fullname,
            username: payload.username,
            password: payload.password,
            confirmPassword: payload.confirmPassword,
        });
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

export const getCurrentUserAvatar = createAsyncThunk('superadmin/getAvatar', async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('User/avatar');
        return response.url;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

export const updateCurrentUserAvatar = createAsyncThunk('superadmin/updateAvatar', async (avatar) => {
    try {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('avatar', avatar);
        const response = await axios.post('User/avatar', formData, {
            headers: { 'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data' },
        });
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

export const superAdminSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'superadmin',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setPage: (state, action) => {
            state.currentPage = action.payload;
        },
        setSearch: (state, action) => {
            state.search = action.payload;
            state.currentPage = 1;
        },
        setLock: (state, action) => {
            state.isLocked = action.payload;
        },
        setImage: (state, action) => {
            console.log(action);
            state.avatar = action.payload;
        },
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(getAdminData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.data = action.payload.data;
                state.count = action.payload.count;
            })
            .addCase(updateAdminStatus.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.adminId = action.payload.adminId;
                state.isLocked = action.payload.isLocked;
            })
            .addCase(createAdmin.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.admins.push(action.payload);
            })
            .addCase(getCurrentUserAvatar.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.avatar = action.payload;
            })
            .addCase(updateCurrentUserAvatar.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.avatar = action.payload;
            });
    },
});

export const { setPage, setSearch, setLock, setImage } = superAdminSlice.actions;

export default superAdminSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Remove `headers: { 'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }`, and see what you get then.

Comment: still same error @CBroe

Answer (score 2):

You need to add fieldName as "file" instead of "avatar", your error says file field is require but you added "avatar" make sure to send field name as "file" while sending blob

```
export const updateCurrentUserAvatar = createAsyncThunk('superadmin/updateAvatar', async (avatar) => {
    try {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', avatar);
        const response = await axios.post('User/avatar', formData, {
            headers: { 'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data' },
        });
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```